# How to keep font quality on scale transform

Tags: wpf, vb.net, text

I want to stretch the text in a label to fill the width of the label using VB.NET code. This is in a WPF application.

I have tried numerous methods including changing only the font size like this:

```
scale = 0.25    
lbl.FontSize = l.Width * scale
```

The problem with this method is I need the height to remain the same for all labels and the 0.25 was a guess that gives approximately the correct fill for a string of 4 characters

I tried a recursive method where I change the font size in small increments and compare the string width to the label width until it fits.

Transformations was also considered and it would looks like a good bet:

```
w = lbl.Width
scale = lbl.content.length/100
lbl.LayoutTransform = New System.Windows.Media.ScaleTransform(w * scale, 1)
```

This solves my problem of hight but I still need to guess the factor of transformation until it sort of works.  Also the stretched text lose it quality and becomes distorted as expected.

Is there any way to reduce the distortion effect on text when its transformed.  Perhaps some fonts that display better than other on after transformations?

Comment: This is never going to look good.  Change your design so you don't have to solve this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. I eventually resolved by changing the font size of all labels to the label with the smallest font, this way the text will always fit and the heights will also match.